# Using custom JGroups module in JBoss EAP

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jboss6.x, jgroups

I have JBoss EAP 6.4 and JGroups 3.2.13 in it. To migrate the application to Amazon ECS using Service Discovery I need DNS_PING protocol ([article about migration](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrate-wildfly-cluster-to-ecs-using-service-discovery/)). The issue is that DNS_PING was added only in JGroups 4.0.12 ([github link](https://github.com/belaban/JGroups/blob/master/src/org/jgroups/protocols/dns/DNS_PING.java)) so I can not easily include it.

My initial idea was to implement own module for JBoss and include missing classes in it. But it seems that there are dependencies on other parts of JGroups that are different from 4 to 3.2 versions (utils classes, logging etc).

Another solution may be to replace existing JGroups 3.2.13 with the entire module of more recent version. Unfortunately I can not update to JBoss EAP 7 but can just replace a module from it. The issue is that other modules in JBoss depending on JGroups and I am wondering if there is a back capability JGroups from 4 to 3?

Is there any other possible option? Or can you advise anything about such updates of core modules?

Comment: You can't expect that it will be compatible after swapping major version. If you're stuck at old version, the best solution is probably backporting DNS_PING  yourselves.

Comment: Unfortunately there are differences in interface that protocol class should implement in JGroups 3 and 4 versions. So after spending some time on backporting DNS_PING I decided to switch to JDBC_PING approach implemented in 3rd version.

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively try to backport NATIVE_S3_PING to 3.2.13, this may be simpler than DNS_PING, as it is hosted in a different repo.

[1] https://github.com/jgroups-extras/native-s3-ping/blob/master/src/org/jgroups/aws/s3/NATIVE_S3_PING.java

Comment: Thank you for advice! I used JDBC_PING but this is also a good alternative.